# When does an ordered set have a supremum?

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

My textbook states that an ordered set S has the least upper bound property if the following is true:
If $E \subset S, E $ is not empty and is bounded above, then $sup E$ exists in S.
But consider the set of rational numbers $\mathbb Q$, and a subset $S = {{1,2,3}}$. $S$ is not empty. It's also bounded above. $sup S=3$ also exists in $\mathbb Q$. But the set of rational numbers does not have a supremum!

Comment: The definition should say "**For any** $E\subset S$, if $E$ is not empty and bounded above then $\sup E$ exists in $S$". All you've done is show this for one particular $E$, namely $E=\{1,2,3\}$. On the other hand, there exists some other set $E'\subset \Bbb{Q}$ which is non-empty and bounded above, but $\sup E'\notin \Bbb{Q}$ (e.g $E'=\{q\in \Bbb{Q}\,: q^2<2\}$).

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that the sum and inf are not in the set. For example; consider the set

$$E= \{ \frac{1}{x}| x \in \mathbb{N}\}.$$

It is clear that $\inf{E}=0$ but $0 \not \in E$.

Answer (score 0):

Not, The set $S$ has a supremum but it is in $\mathbb{R}$. The supremum (and infimum) of a set can be not in that set.